# Oddity with tag synonym interface

Tags: discussion, tagging

Not really a question, but an observation designed to reduce frustration:

I just went on a tag pluralization spree, converting `list` to `big-list` or `lists` as appropriate and `footnote` to `footnotes`. Following the model that others have started, I then tried to suggest `footnote` as a synonym for `footnotes`. This was disallowed as I'd managed to purge all `footnote` tags from the system. This surprised me a bit and even once I'd purged, it seemed useful to introduce the synonym for future proofing the use of the singular form.

So, I went back and reverted one of my retags. I still couldn't suggest. I remained puzzled for a bit. I then noticed that @Juan had reinstituted my change to `footnotes`.

The moral? 1) @Juan, no, I wasn't in the grips of transitory insanity. 2) If going on a "tag sweep," suggest synonyms before done.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that if moderators do this tag merging then it happens without bumping everything to the front page.  Not much of a bother now, but later on I think that these retagging sprees will get a bit irritating so perhaps the best strategy is to have a permanent discussion here on meta where retagging proposals can be raised and discussed (MathOverflow has this on its meta site).

Comment: Your thought is correct. Tag merges do not count as edits to questions, while manual retagging does. On meta.so, it is common to have questions tagged [retag-request]. For example, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54316/remove-the-ansi-c-tag).